Flutter RichText with TextSpans for Localization
I have a text to be displayed. Someparts of it have to be bold and tappable. RichText with TextSpans are great, but a problem during localizations. Any suggestions?
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: text1.color, fontSize: text1.size.style.fontSize),
              text: text1.text),
          TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: text2.color,
                  fontSize: text2.size.style.fontSize,
                  fontWeight: text2.fontWeight.fontWeight),
              text: text2.text,
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () => _onTapEula(context)),
          TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: text3.color, fontSize: text3.size.style.fontSize),
              text: text3.text),
          TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: text4.color,
                  fontSize: text4.size.style.fontSize,
                  fontWeight: text4.fontWeight.fontWeight),
              text: text4.text,
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () => _onTapPrivacyStatement(context)),
        ],
      ),


What's the problem? It will be great if you can show the prblm in some image screenshot.
Also if you are facing some textAlign or ellipse problem in RichText(), you can try Text.rich()
It works same but some prblm can be solved with that.

The issue is not in english. Here I'm hardcoding 4 TextSpans with all the custom styling. But in other languages the order could be different. I want the styling to happen accordingly. Basically I'm tying to apply the styling and tappable text spans to only those words after localization.

Ok, I understand there is some issue with other languages regarding order but it is hard to understand what your goal is, if it is possible can you add images comparing any particular language having prblm like Polish with english.
like witam in Polish and Hello in English.
Just give us 2 screenshot one in English text and 1 in other language to compare and then tell us the prblm

Just an example - I don't understand polish but the order clearly get's jumbled on localization: "By checking this box, you confirm that you have read, understood, and accept BOBOBO's License Agreement and Privacy Statement." becomes "Zaznaczając to pole, potwierdzasz, że przeczytałeś, zrozumiałeś i akceptujesz Umowę licencyjną i Oświadczenie o ochronie prywatności BOBOBO."

I want to highlight and make only Privacy Statement and License Agreement (onTap would open the document in a Sheet or a link etc)

Ok now i understand. This thing is not possible with richText, my suggestion is you use regex for that.
For every word you want to highlight and make clickable enclosed it with [],
then in the widget traverse the string and break string into list of RichText() , you can do that using regex in that way you will make anything highlight and clickable that lie inside [] like how we do in markdown for link  some thing like that.

Ohh that's interesting, I will try this. The issue here is that this modification will also have to be done for all the translations as well, but if it works well then shouldn't be a problem. Thank you.

you can even add links for that or any other property like color of text with () for word and perform it dynamically. But take precaution when defining the actual string in various languages the syntax should be accurate to your logic
